# How to get Text of Div

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML

```
<div>abc, deef, aas,a, <span>this is span</span></div>
```

how to get the text of the only div element not span in it included.
e.g abc, deef, aas, a,

I write the following code but it returns all the text inside itself and its child elements.

```
var text = $("div").text()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
var text = $("div").contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wB5Tu/)

Answer (score 1):

Try filtering the contents

```
var text =   $('div').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
    }).text()
```

http://api.jquery.com/contents/

EDIT: Damn, beaten to it :(

Comment: Have an upvote anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var txt = $('div').text().replace($('div span').text(),"");
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/Tks5L/4/

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following function:

```
var text = $("div").html();
```

Comment: It does the same as `$("div").text()`

Comment: This does not works try once before you say.. (btw I have not downvoted you..)

Comment: @pbibergal Not at all. `.html()` returns the text AND the HTML inside instead of only the text between tags.

Comment: Still it will return text within span element

Comment: Still it's not the same.